# How to use getopt()

Tags: c

it's 3 hours that I'm looking on internet and i cannot find a solution. I have to create a small program using getopt that accept 3 argument, m and n and --help. I want to be able to write an integer for m and n as option or leave it without any number. Example: -m print first message, -n print second message, -m 1 -n 33 here print a message for m with the number and one for n with the number, --help print third message

```
while ((c = getopt (argc, argv, "m:n:help")) != -1)
        switch (c)
          {
          case 'm':
            integer1 = atoid(optarg);
            printf("Hello1 %d", integer1);
            break;
          case 'n':
            integer2 = atoid(optarg);
            printf("Hello2 %d", integer2);
            break;
          case 'help':
           printf("Tutorial");
            break;

          default:
            printf("to be tested");
            break;
          }
```

That is the code to parse the -m and -n with the number but i don't know how to implement the -m and -n without the number.

Comment: First hit using Google `c getopt`: [Parsing program options using getopt.](http://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Getopt.html)

Comment: Your code does not accept `--help` as an argument, it accepts `-h`, `-e`, `-l`, and `-p` as arguments. Further, `'help'` is not a character string, it's (strangely enough) a 32 bit integer whose in-memory represntation will have those characters.

Comment: `getopt` supports neither long options like `--help` nor options with optional arguments.

Comment: SO is no tutorial site.

Comment: I've already checked the website gnu.org but it's even more confused. Again i don't know how to use get opt when -n for example have the number or not.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to support options with optional arguments or long options, `getopt` will not do what you want.  You need to use `getopt_long`.